# Need changes to A* algorithm so it will work with rotating of agent

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I'm writing a simple A* algorithm for finding the shortest path. But I need something more complicated. The agent can only go forward and rotate(90 deg). Will it influence at path or I can use simple A*? 
Thanks for all.

```py
def astar(maze, start, end):

    start_node = Node(None, start)
    start_node.g = start_node.h = start_node.f = 0
    end_node = Node(None, end)
    end_node.g = end_node.h = end_node.f = 0

    open_list = []
    closed_list = []

    open_list.append(start_node)
    while len(open_list) > 0:
        current_node = open_list[0]
        current_index = 0
        for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
            if item.f < current_node.f:
                current_node = item
                current_index = index

        open_list.pop(current_index)
        closed_list.append(current_node)
        if current_node == end_node:
            path = []
            current = current_node
            while current is not None:
                path.append(current.position)
                current = current.parent
            return path[::-1]
        children = []
        for new_position in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]:
            node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1])
            if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1) or node_position[1] < 0:
                continue
            if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] != 0:
                continue
            new_node = Node(current_node, node_position)
            children.append(new_node)
        for child in children:
            for closed_child in closed_list:
                if child == closed_child:
                    continue
            child.g = current_node.g + 1
            child.h = ((child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) ** 2) + ((child.position[1] - end_node.position[1]) ** 2)
            child.f = child.g + child.h
            for open_node in open_list:
                if child == open_node and child.g > open_node.g:
                    continue
            open_list.append(child)
```

Comment: That's not how we post code to stack overflow.  Please copy-paste your code into this question and use the `{}` button to format it nicely.

Comment: @Hoog code is too long. Mb my github rep with this code?

Comment: If there is a cost for rotating, then it will affect the path.  Otherwise no

Comment: You can use simple `A*` -- rotation is merely one type of state transition.

Comment: I'm not particularly clear on what you're asking.  You've posted a generic question on feasibility, but added a block of code with no shown problem.

Comment: @Prune it is only theoretical question.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that the A* algorithm needs to be made aware of the fact that there's a difference between "being at position (x, y) facing in direction d<sub>1</sub>" and "being at position (x, y) facing in direction d<sub>2</sub>." If the algorithm doesn't know this, it can't give you back the best series of instructions to follow.

One way that you can solve this is to imagine that your world isn't a 2D grid, but actually a 3D space consisting of four copies of the 2D grid stacked on top of one another. Just as your position in the 2D space consists of your current (x, y) coordinate, your position in the 3D space consists of your current (x, y) coordinate, combined with the direction that you're facing.

Imagine what it means to move around in this space. You have two options for the action you can take - "move" or "turn 90°" The "move" action will move you one step forward in the current 2D slice you're in, where "forward" has a different meaning based on what slice you're in. In other words, "move" will cause you to move purely within the X/Y plane, keeping your direction fixed. The "turn" operation will keep your X/Y position fixed, but will change which plane that you're in (based on which direction you happen to be facing at the time).

If you encode this information explicitly into your search, then A* can use it to find the best path for you to take. You'll need to define some new heuristic that estimates the distance to the goal. One option would be to assume there are no walls and to determine how many steps you'd have to take, plus the number of rotations needed, to get to the goal. At that point, A* can give you the best path to follow, using your heuristic to guide its search.

More generally, many problems of the form "I have a position in the world, plus some extra state (orientation, velocity, etc.)" can be converted from pathfinding in 2D space to pathfinding in 3D space, where your third dimension would be that extra piece of information. Or perhaps it'll go up to 4D or 5D space if you have multiple extra pieces of information.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to divide the sourcecode into two functions: the forward model of the agent and the (path)planning algorithm itself. In the forward model, it's specified, that the agent has three possible actions (forward, rotleft, rotright). The A* planner creates the gametree for the agent. A possible sequence is: left, forward, forward.

It's not a classical pathplanning problem but an AI planning problem. Realizing such a two layer system is more complicated over a normal A* wayfinding algorithm, because the rotation action doesn't bring the agent nearer to the goal. It's more complicated to decide, if a simulated action has improved the situation or was a step backward.

In a real life scenario, even the described separation into forward model and planner wouldn't solve the issue, because the state space in a map would be grow very fast. Additional heuristics are needed to guide the A* planner into the optimal direction.

Comment: I don't think you need to need to make this into a two-layer system like this. By changing the state space, you can use A* just as before, but with a slightly more complex heuristic.